# Filter with VBA cells by several background colors at once

Tags: vba, filter, colors, background

Can I filter cells with VBA by several background colors at once? The line below does not work.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$$A$5").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array(RGB(228, 223, 236), RGB(218, 238, 243), RGB(183, 222, 232)), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. At least not with the AutoFilter. You can't do it in raw Excel, Autofilter only ever lets you pick one colour.

You could write a macro that hides the unneeded rows though...